# Delphi: Combobox whith ownerdraw and autocomplete

Tags: delphi, combobox, autocomplete, components

I'm trying to have a combobox working like the "Category" one you can find in MS Money:

Items are :

```
Item 1
   - Sub item 1
   - Sub item 2
Item 2
   - Sub item a
   - Sub item b
   - ...
```

When you select Sub item 1, it shows: "`Item 1 : Sub item 1"`

I manage to do that with OwnerDraw style, but then the combobox is in read-only. I want to be able to add custom items.

Does someone know how to do that ? (Or a third party component)

Comment: What do you mean by "loose auto completion". I just ran a test and Auto Completion works just fine with Owner Draw enabled. What are you typing and causing the Auto Complete to fail? What did you expect to select?

Comment: @Cosmin
Sorry, I was not clear: I do not loose autocompletion, the combobox is in readonly, i can't enter a custom text

Comment: @Cosmin Prund: How do you mean `Auto Completion works just fine with Owner Draw enabled`? Is the text box editable? I think Fred is talking about editable owner draw combobox.

Comment: @Fred: How would you expect it to work? When a new item is entered, what should it be, specifically an `Item` or a `Sub item`, as per your example? And if it should only be a sub item, for example, then how would you decide which item it should belong to?

Comment: @Andriy M, the edit box is not enabled but the combo box reacts to keyboard input, and does "auto select".

Comment: @Andriy M: In my example: if you select, Sub Item 1, by default it shows "     - Sub Item 1". With ownerdraw i manage to shows "Item 1 : Sub Item 1". But then the combobox is no more editable. This is my problem

Comment: @Fred: I don't think the actual TComboBox component can be made to behave like that, i.e. be editable *and* allow you to draw the items in a customised way at the same time. By the way, you didn't answer how you would decide which Item to add the new Sub-item to. Seems like you'd have to introduce some sort of syntax to allow the user to specify the relation, like `Item A:Sub-item 1`, the `:` being a specific divider between the item and sub-item parts.

Comment: @Fred: Anyway, there doesn't seem to be a really easy way, though I myself might try to put a borderless TEdit over the combo box's client area to (try to) get the desired effect. (As you may have guessed, I don't know about any ready-made components that have implemented what you want.)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing but I suggest you to explore the opensource [Monex](http://sourceforge.net/projects/monex/) project.

It seems to uses some components implementing similar features.